# Python nested loops issues

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to learn Python and I am writing a few scripts for fun to get used to the language.

I am trying to create a script that will roll 3 'dice' and if all 3 return 6, it will write it to a list, otherwise roll again and update the counter.

All this is supposed to happen a large amount of times, so that I can get a large list and then calculate the average amount of rolls needed to get triple 6.

After many iterations this is my code right now (probably sub-optimal since I edited it a lot to try and find a way for it to work)

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

from random import randint

first = randint(0,5)
second = randint(0,5)
third = randint(0,5)
count = 1
list = []

for_list =  range(10000)

for item in for_list:
        while first != 5 or second != 5 or third != 5:
                count+=1
                first = randint(0,5)
                second = randint(0,5)
                third = randint(0,5)
                if first == 5 and second == 5 and third == 5:
                        list.append(count)
                        count = 1
print sum(list) / float(len(list))

print list
```

Right now it seems like the while loop works, but I cant figure out how to get it to actually run many times (the for loop, in this example 10,000 times).

This is my output (prints "average" and the list, containing the count variable:

```
218.0
[218]
```

So in this run it took 218 rolls. After that the script ends.
Can anyone help me understand why the script isn't running the for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why doesn't the next iteration of the `for` loop start, then? The code above looks valid to me.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: it starts, but the `while` condition is always going to be  false after the first match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your boolean condition is at fault here:

```
first != 5 or second != 5 or third != 5
```

This is only ever `False` if all three values are set to `5`. The moment you find a triple-5 set, your `while` loop is **always** going to be `False`.

So after finding your first match, from there on out your `first`, `second` and `third` variables are set to `5`, and the `while` loop is never entered the other 9999 times your `for` loop iterates.

Rather than use a `while` loop here, just use a large number of iterations and roll the dice each iteration, then use a simple `if` to add it to the list:

```
results = []
counter = 0

for iteration in xrange(10 ** 6):  # 1 million times
    counter += 1
    roll = random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
    if roll == (6, 6, 6):
        results.append(counter)
        counter = 0
```

I used a better name for the results list; you want to avoid using the same name as a built-in type for your variables. Since you are using Python 2, I also switched to using `xrange()`; no point in building a whole list of integers just to control how many times your loop should repeat.

I used a tuple to store the three dice rolls, and picked numbers from 1 to 6 to match the conventional dice numbers. You can then test if a match is found by comparing against another tuple of 3 numbers.

Demo:

```
>>> results = []
>>> counter = 0
>>> for iteration in xrange(10 ** 6):  # 1 million times
...     counter += 1
...     roll = random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
...     if roll == (6, 6, 6):
...         results.append(counter)
...         counter = 0
... 
>>> sum(results, 0.0) / len(results)
217.40704500978472
>>> len(results)
4599
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! your tip about the boolean returning false helped me realise that I need to roll another time for new random numbers or I will remain with 5 5 5. This allowed me to make the script work!

Comment: Also thanks for the other tips. I am a Python newbie and seeing better ways to tackle things is great for me

Answer (score 1):

After a few modifications, I believe this may be what you want:

```
from random import randint

first = randint(0,5)
second = randint(0,5)
third = randint(0,5)
count = 1
list = []

for_list = 10001
completed = 0

while completed < for_list:
    completed = completed+1
    count=count+1
    first = randint(0,5)
    second = randint(0,5)
    third = randint(0,5)
    if first == 5 and second == 5 and third == 5:
        list.append(count)
        count = 1

print sum(list) / float(len(list))

print list
```

Which returned;

`172.071428571
[214, 196, 44, 14, 43, 31, 427, 179, 427, 48, 134, 78, 261, 256, 36, 242, 244, 40, 189, 53, 140, 690, 26, 802, 39, 45, 2, 93, 30, 26, 351, 117, 455, 24, 190, 359, 83, 23, 60, 81, 38, 3, 173, 205, 175, 689, 233, 59, 26, 122, 263, 415, 211, 38, 94, 100]`

EDIT: As Martijn Pieters (below) has said, you could remove the

```
first = randint(0,5)
second = randint(0,5)
third = randint(0,5)
```

from the outside of the loop.

Comment: Why run `randint` outside of the `while` loop *at all*?

Comment: I was modifying his script to do what he wanted, not rewriting it from the ground up.